# replace setInterval with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sqlite

thanks in advance for your help! I am working with (and super new to) JavaScript, node.js with express, and sqlite3.  I am trying to make an AJAX request to get a list of all the messages that have been posted to the chatroom page:

```
var meta = document.querySelector('meta[name=roomName]');
var roomName = meta.content;

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
     var intervalID = setInterval(updateMessages, 4000);
}, false);

function updateMessages() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', '/' + roomName + '/messages.json', true);
    req.send();
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = req.responseText;
}
```

Two questions: 1. I think I should be using setTimeout instead of setInterval. How would I go about switching to using this method?  2. Is the server-side code below that corresponds to the code above correct? How do I get access to the data that comes back after this request?

```
app.get('/:roomName/messages.json', function(request, response){
    var roomName = request.params.roomName;
    var sql = "SELECT ALL body FROM messages where room="+roomName+";";
    conn.query(sql, function(error, result) { 
      if(error) {
        console.log("There was an error.");
      }
      response.send(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: First, you should use ajax instead of sjax. And you have an SQL injection problem

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: An interval is the right approach for a poll, but not a very good solution. Since you have a Node backend, you could setup WebSockets easily that will communicate efficiently with your client. Have a look at http://socket.io/

Comment: I am randomly generating the room names, so I thought it would be okay to pass the variable right in. How else could I do it?

Comment: I updated it. Is this better?

Comment: app.get('/:roomName/messages.json', function(request, response){
    // fetch all of the messages for this room
    var pars = [request.params.roomName];

    var sql = "SELECT ALL body FROM messages where room=$1;";
    conn.query(sql, pars, function(error, result) { 
      if(error) {
        console.log("There was an error.");
      }
      console.log(result);
      response.send(result);
    });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` is the appropriate thing to use here.

However, keep in mind that you will never see any messages because AJAX is *asynchronous*, so `req.responseText` won't have anything. You should use a `readystatechange` event:

```
req.open(......);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( this.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
req.send();
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Why put req.send() after instead of before the readystatechange event?

Comment: Because that's the order you're supposed to put them in.

Comment: Haha ok, just doesn't make sense to me why.

Comment: Similar reasons why you set `img.onload` before you set `img.src`

Comment: well something is working now! But I can't figure out how to turn the JSON info into a JavaScript object...any ideas?